Сделать динамичное значение @allure.title из списка
Приветы. Использую @pytest.mark.parametrize и @allure.title, вот во второй хочу,
чтобы попадало новое имя теста, каждый раз при итерации параметрации.
data_names = ('Имя раз', "Имя два")



@pytest.mark.parametrize('data', data_names)
@allure.title(f"{data_names}")
def test_name(arg1, arg2, data):
    тело теста

В данном примере, почему-то в allure-title попадает ('Имя раз', "Имя два")

Посмотрите функцию next.
